# Visual Studio carriage return goes to far left in JS editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm not sure what happened, but when I perform a carriage return, the cursor ends up at the far left of the editor. I've already reset the settings but it still happens. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Having the same issue.  I've linted it and I still have this issue.  Did you figure this out?